# Ionic - AdMob Pro Below Tab Bar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-admob

I have followed the tutorial/installation guide set out on the ReadMe.md file and am trying to find a way to position the banner at the bottom of the view but on top of the tab bar which I currently have.

Currently the banner ads show below the tab bar (see image) but they should site on top of it and at the same time not overlap the content. Is there a setting I am missing here?

Code:

```
  AdMob.createBanner( {
    adId: admobid.banner,
    position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    isTesting: true, // TODO: remove this line when release
    overlap: false,
    offsetBottomBar: true,
    offsetTopBar: false
  } );
```

[image]

Comment: This is discouraged, read https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287 and see ionic instructions here https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps and positioning instructions here https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/setOptions#options

Comment: @Miquel Thanks for the links - so I guess it's best to place at the top or not at all and use interstitial instead?

Comment: sure! You could also place a divider between the tabbar and the banner (via css). I think it can be a mess as the margins are delicated, but in fact, achievable. If you can place interstitials and it's not too much intrusive, this is the best option in terms of monetization. See https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/showInterstitialAd

Comment: @Miquel Thank you - I have interstitials working now so think I will use them on launch of the app :)